# Kotlin - Is there a way of defining an explicit scope of a function with receiver defined in companion object?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Imagine you have a following code:

```
interface SomeClient {

    fun isValid(value: String): Boolean
}

class SomeData private constructor(
    val value: String
) {

    companion object {

        fun SomeClient.create(value: String): SomeData? =
            if (isValid(value)) {
                SomeData(value)
            } else {
                null
            }
    }
}

class SomeOtherData private constructor(
    val otherValue: String
) {

    companion object {

        fun SomeClient.create(value: String): SomeOtherData? =
            if (isValid(value)) {
                SomeOtherData(value)
            } else {
                null
            }
    }
}

class SomeUseCase(
    someClient: SomeClient
) : SomeClient by someClient {

    fun run() {
        val someData = SomeData.create("hello")
        val someOtherData = SomeOtherData.create("wassup")
    }
}
```

The whole intent is to provide a static factory method to create a valid value objects (`SomeData`, `SomeOtherData`) but the validation logic includes some IO operation. So I want to limit the scope of where the create methods may be called to classes that implement `SomeClient`.

The problem here is that the compiler can't resolve the companion object methods (`SomeData#create`, `SomeOtherData#create`) inside of the `SomeUseCase#run`, it complains that the receiver is incorrect.

Of course I could do it like that

```
class SomeUseCase {
    fun run() {
        val someData = this.createSomeData(...)
        val someOtherData = this.createSomeOtherData(...)
    }
}
```

and rename the creation methods accordingly, but I want to keep the names so it would be `SomeData.create`, not `SomeData.createSomeData`.

Is there a way to achieve this? Does it make sense at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `fun SomeClient.create(value: String)` in `SomeData` companion object you are not defining `create` method for companion object, but an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) for `SomeClient`in the scope of companion object.

If you rewrite it so that it become a method of companion object, you will see that there is no receiver for `isValid`() call, so it need to be passed there as a parameter:

```kotlin
class SomeData private constructor(val value: String) {
    companion object {
        fun create(value: String, validator: SomeClient): SomeData? =
            if (validator.isValid(value)) SomeData(value) else null
    }
}
```

After that it may be called in the scope of `SomeClient` like that:

```kotlin
val someData = SomeData.create("hello", this)
```

It's a bit cumbersome to repeat `this` for each creation call, so you may define an extension function for `SomeData` companion object in the scope of `SomeClient` interface:

```kotlin
interface SomeClient {
    fun isValid(value: String): Boolean

    fun SomeData.Companion.create(value: String) = create(value, this@SomeClient)
}
```

After that it may be called in the scope of `SomeClient` in a desired way:

```kotlin
val someData = SomeData.create("hello")
```